# ActionBarSherlock [Sliding Left Menu] [Company Logo] [Sliding Right Menu] how do i code that on my XML?

Tags: android

I am having trouble using ActionBarSherlock how do I create a interface on my actionbar where [Sliding Left Menu] [Company Logo] [Sliding Right Menu]  , Sliding left menu on the left of the action bar while company logo on the middle and the sliding right menu on the right of the bar? Can anyone give me a sample XML.